# On / of one's own accord

Tags: idioms

When it comes to the idiom involving the phrase "own accord", is it considered correct to say "*on one's own accord*", instead of "*of one's own accord*"? To me, the former sounds more natural. Example: "*the autodidact enjoyed learning on her own accord*".

Comment: The specific preposition is a matter of arbitrarily-established idiomatic usage, which [as this NGrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+his+own+accord%2Cof+his+own+accord&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20his%20own%20accord%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20his%20own%20accord%3B%2Cc0), overwhelmingly favours ***of***. I'm sure at least some (perhaps *most*) of the relatively few people who use ***on*** are getting mixed up with *"**on his own account**"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Andreas: I have never heard "on" used with "own accord" before. Furthermore looking at a [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20your%20own%20accord%2Cof%20your%20own%20accord&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20your%20own%20accord%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20your%20own%20accord%3B%2Cc0) of "on your own accord" vs. "of your own accord" shows that "of" is an order of magnitude more common.

The phrase "of own accord" is also [listed in the idiom dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+own+accord) at dictionary.com and used as a frequent example in definitions of "accord", whereas "on" is not.

I think "on one's own accord" is simply incorrect.

Comment: My skill in identifying the various pieces of grammar is pale in comparison to the rest of you, but I will say that a switch in my brain went off when watching a TV show, and a detective said: "She left on her own accord."  I had to pause the show and say... is that correct?  I thought about it and believed that 'She left of her own accord.' sounded more correct.  I will admit that I get by thinking more of 'what sounds correct' than what is grammatically correct.  Thank you for the well-explained clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever heard "on one's own accord." It sounds to me like a hybrid of the (standard) expressions "of one's own accord" and "on one's own initiative."